# Git merge repositories into same root folder

Tags: git, version-control

We have two repositories we want to merge, frontend and shared Is it possible to do this:

1. Create a new branch in frontend from the first commit (where there was nothing committed)
2. Apply all the history of all the branches of shared onto the new blank branch in frontend.
3. Do a massive merge of the new branch(s) into the main branch, so we keep all the histories of both repositories?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you would 'Apply all the history' and do 'a massive merge' but to answer the question title, I would do it through a remote, e.g. github:

- Push repository A to github
- Create a new branch in repository B
- Switch to that branch
- Add repository A as a remote
- pull from repository A which will merge the 2.